# Smileys not displaying in input box codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using smiley helper to display and store smileys. Smileys 've displayed in a generated table view. Click on the smiley,corresponding text gets displayed not the smiley. Here is my code in Library,

```
 public function get_smiles() 
{
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('smiley');
$CI->load->library('table');
$image_array = get_clickable_smileys('images/smileys/', 'editor-textarea');
$col_array = $CI->table->make_columns($image_array, 8);
$array['smiley_table'] = $CI->table->generate($col_array);
return  $array['smiley_table'];
}
```

In view,

```
<?php echo smiley_js(); ?>
<textarea name="editor-textarea" class="editor-textarea" id="editor-textarea"><textarea>

<ul>
  <li>
  <?php $smiles = $this->common->get_smiles(); ?>
  <?php echo $smiles; ?>
 </li>
```

How do I solve this?

Smiley js

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   /*<![CDATA[ */var smiley_map = {};

        function insert_smiley(smiley, field_id) {
            var el = document.getElementById(field_id), newStart;

            if ( ! el && smiley_map[field_id]) {
                el = document.getElementById(smiley_map[field_id]);

                if ( ! el)
                    return false;
            }

            el.focus();
            smiley = " " + smiley;

            if ('selectionStart' in el) {
                newStart = el.selectionStart + smiley.length;

                el.value = el.value.substr(0, el.selectionStart) +
                                smiley +
                                el.value.substr(el.selectionEnd, el.value.length);
                el.setSelectionRange(newStart, newStart);
            }
            else if (document.selection) {
                document.selection.createRange().text = smiley;
            }
        }// ]]>
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you also share the smiley_js as that will be what is inserting the smiley into the text box.

Comment: question updated

Comment: The JS is only looking for an ID, so I would remove the class on the text editor as you should not have a class name the same as an ID. I can't see why this should not be working. So let me copy this into my CI instance to test it.

Comment: Your text area element has a typo. You need to close it, notice the / missing in the closing <textarea> tag. <textarea name="editor-textarea" class="editor-textarea" id="editor-textarea"></textarea>.

Answer (score 1):

After testing it, I've found that it is working as it should.

You can't add an image to the text area. Looking at the JS, it will add the text version of the smiley. Example of one, you can see the '%-P'.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="insert_smiley('%-P', 'editor-textarea')"><img src="assets/images/smileys/tongue_rolleye.gif" alt="tongue rolleye" style="width: 19; height: 19; border: 0;"></a>
```

Depending on your needs, it is your job to show the smiley on submission, so if it is a comments section for example you'd need to parse it on page load or via an AJAX callback on submit.

You need to convert the text version of the emoji into the correct image. You can do this with a [CI function](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/smiley_helper.html#parse_smileys).

```
parse_smileys([$str = ''[, $image_url = ''[, $smileys = NULL]]])
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Here's how to use it.

```
echo parse_smileys(':-)', 'assets/images/smileys/');
```

This is parsing the text version of the smiley which you will need to store somewhere, then it goes into the function and you also need to pass the location of the smiley images. Here's it working in my CI program, the single smiley has been parsed from the code sample above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code.Can you give me an idea to pass the text version  and display it as smiley through the function parse_smileys